# HOWTO Set Column Value on Join Table Record for Many-to-Many Association

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I’m trying to make the most out of the conveniences/automagic of the Phoenix/Ecto frameworks to handle database INSERTs wherever possible. However, I’m finding it a bit difficult in my case of using a `many_to_many` association.

To elaborate more:

- I have three schemas that form the `many_to_many` association: `User`, `Organisation`, and `Membership`
- To spell it out, Users have many Organisations via Memberships, and Organisations have many Users via Memberships
- Membership records also have a `user_role` column to specify the role of the user in relation to the associated organisation (e.g., creator, administrator, etc.)
- When a new user signs up, the sign up form also provides a name field so the user can provide the name of their organisation.

  - This part is key because it means that the `User` form has nested inputs for `Organisation`
  - I also **do not** want to expose the `user_role` field on the form. This is something I want the system to manage behind the scenes.
  - To illustrate, the struct returned by the form looks like this:

```
%{
   "email" => "test@test.com",
   "password" => "elixirrocks", 
   "organisations" => %{"0" => %{"name" => "ACME CO."}}
}
```

With the associations set properly in the relevant Ecto schemas, this struct will insert into the database using the following set of operations:

```
%User{}
 |> User.changeset(attrs)
 |> Repo.insert()
```

However, what I would like to do is set the `user_role` to a specific value (e.g., creator) somehow without changing the set of operations shown above. In other words, is there a way to set the `user_role` somehow on the `attrs` that Phoenix/Ecto would pick up and store in the `Membership` record?

If not, how would I go about doing this? Would I need to execute this operation with three separate INSERTs (wrapped in a transaction):

1. INSERT user
2. INSERT organisation
3. INSERT membership with user_role

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: this should help, https://elixirforum.com/t/confussed-with-build-assoc-vs-put-assoc-vs-cast-assoc/29116

Comment: perhaps you want to set a default `user_role` value in the user schema, something like `field :user_role, Role, default: :creator`, not sure what type is `user_role` field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to share how I resolved this issue, which was not as trivial as I expected it to be. Thankfully, the Elixir community on Discord was able to guide me through a lot of this, so sending them a big thanks for all the help! Thank you!

There were a few things that I did not mention in my original post that complicated the matter. They were:

1. Relying on Phoenix's nested forms to handle `many-to-many` associations
2. Using `cast_assoc` in the `User.changeset` to handle nested data
3. `NOT NULL CONSTRAINT` on the `user_role` field on the `membership` table – the `JOIN` table

Generally speaking, the key was to step away from the conveniences of the Phoenix framework and take a more "step-by-step" approach. In summary, the approach was to:

1. Breakdown the `INSERT`s for each table separately
2. Use `Ecto.Multi` and `Ecto.Repo.transaction()` to execute the `INSERT`s as a single transaction
3. Remove, or rather do not use, `cast_assoc` within any `changeset` function
4. Manually set the `user_role` on the membership
5. Create an `embedded_schema` to represent the form, extract relevant values for each table and cast those values as appropriate using the relevant `changeset` function

The birds-eye view of this solution can be seen by looking at the Multi Transaction below:

```
1  Ecto.Multi.new()
2  |> Ecto.Multi.insert(:user, User.registration_changeset(%User{}, attrs))
3  |> Ecto.Multi.insert(:org,  Organisation.changeset(%Organisation{}, %{name: org_name}))
4  |> Ecto.Multi.insert(:membership, fn %{user: user, org: org} ->
5      Membership.membership_changeset(%Membership{}, user, org, %{user_role: "creator"})
6  end)
7  |> Repo.transaction(
```

Some key notes for those who might need them...

#### `cast_assoc` failed because of `NOT NULL CONSTRAINT` on JOIN TABLE field

Originally, the `User.registration_changeset` was this way because I was trying to make use of Phoenix's nested form handlers:

```
1  def registration_changeset(user, attrs, opts \\ []) do
2    user
3    |> cast(attrs, [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password])
4    |> cast_assoc(:organisations, required: false )
5    |> validate_email()
6    |> validate_password(opts)
7  end
```

When I submitted the form, the database would throw the following error.
`ERROR 23502 (not_null_violation) null value in column "user_role" violates not-null constraint`

The culprit was Line 4, the `cast_assoc`, but digging deeper, it's because of the many-to-many association between User and Organisation that was defined by this:

```
many_to_many :users, App.Accounts.User, 
  join_through: App.Organisations.Membership
```

As mentioned, the error was thrown by the database and that's because `cast_assoc` automatically creates the `INSERT` for the JOIN TABLE. However, because `user_role` has a `NOT NULL` constraint, an error was thrown because `user_role` was not set. And from what I've learned, cannot be set when using `cast_assoc`. Hence the need for separate `INSERT`s.

I first tried relaxing the constraint by removing the `NOT NULL` from the `user_role` field in the database and used the same Multi Transaction above, I was not a fan of doing this because it risks data integrity. What ended up happening, however, was two records for an organisation and a membership were being created – a record each for `cast_assoc` and a record each for the `INSERT` in the Multi Transaction.

So, it showed me clearly that `cast_assoc` was not needed (and should not be used) at all if I were breaking down the operation into multiple `INSERT`s. It also forced me to look for another way (see below) and also enabled me to (happily) restore the `NOT NULL` constraint.

#### embedded_schemas instead of nested forms

This is not to knock what the Phoenix Framework has provided to make things more convenient for us via nested forms but to demonstrate when it should be used. When I say nested forms, I'm referring to this guide titled [Polymorphic associations with many to many](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/polymorphic-associations-with-many-to-many.html). In this guide, it details an example of a simple Todo List. Simple in the sense that there the JOIN TABLE does not have additional fields to be set, let alone a `NOT NULL` constraint on one of those fields. In my particular case, a nested form simply would not work.

Similarly, there's an argument that modeling forms this way is coupling it too closely with our database schema, which can lead to other complications down the road. So, in general, decouple I suppose!

I could write more, but I think this sufficiently covers the main areas. If you have any questions, feel free to leave a comment.

Cheers!

Comment: cast_assoc would work too, behind the scenes it works like a transaction. I guess the problem is the documentation on cast_assoc and put_assoc, it is very confusing when you just dive into ecto.

Comment: `cast_assoc` did not work for that reason. `cast_assoc` creates a very simple `INSERT` statement for the association, but the association also requires a `user_role` to be set in order for the `INSERT` to be valid (as per the `NOT NULL` constraint). Perhaps I'm missing something though. Open to hearing how you would solve this scenario with `cast_assoc`! :)